# What's this number in celery stdout output after datetime timestamp

Tags: celery

It's important that I parse it and save as some important piece of information.

But I don't know what it is. Can someone please tell me what it is?

`[2015-04-09 12:45:07,807: WARNING/Worker-3] Some log message, started some task.
[2015-04-09 12:45:07,812: INFO/MainProcess] Task blaah succeeded in 5.35s: None`

The numbers 807, and 812. What are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers you refer to are the milliseconds in the timestamp.

Celery's default log format is:

```
[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s] [%(task_name)s(%(task_id)s)] %(message)s
```

Comment: Thanks, I googled it right after posting, as always happens. Here it is: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-task-log-format